# Statistics needs to be captured for query analysis

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, statistics, performance, performance-testing, query-performance

What statistics are required to theoretically prove that X query work better than Y query. As per my knowledge I need to look for:

- Query elapsed time
- Logical read
- Logical write
- Physical read
- Physical write

Do I need to have other statistics also to measure? Do I also need to measure

- Memory pressure
- TempDb space usage
- Buffer usage
- Query plan (Scan, Seek)

  to get perfect analysis.

Ex scenario:

I have two queries one is using index and one without index. I need to show which query is performing well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25115/discussion-between-zerotoinfinity-and-aaron-bertrand).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are talking about the same query, executing with different indexes.  You can't just arbitrarily compare 2 totally different queries that do 2 different things.  As Aaron stated in the comments, I can compare my 2001 VW to a 2015 Camaro and there will be no correlation, the Camaro may go faster but that's because it has a bigger engine.  Conversely, my VW will get better gas mileage because the engine is smaller.

That being said, I use the `SET` options: `SET STATISTICS TIME, IO ON`

Once those are on, the query will kick out all the CPU usage and reads that have been performed.  See below:

[image]

I then use www.statisticsparser.com to consolidate the data into an easy to read format.  That takes care of CPU/IO.

[image]

Execution plan can be pulled from the "Get Actual Execution plan" option in SSMS .  The execution plan will also have the memory grant (how much memory is allocated to the query).

[image]